# belongs_to with condition to find master parent doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

I have these two activerecord models:

```
Milestone
  has_many :nodes

Node
  belongs_to :milestone
```

Milestones can have multiple nodes because it's possible to create aliases. I then need a way to find the master node.

I tried two options but none of them work completely:

Option 1: add an association :node :

```
 belongs_to :node, conditions: {is_alias: true}
```

Looks obvious to me but doesn't work at all. When I do @milestone.node, the result is "nil"

Option 2: create a node method:

```
  def node
     Node.where(milestone_id: self.id, is_alias: false)
  end
```

This works halfway:

@milestone.node => returns the right node

@milestone.node.milestone => returns an error: undefined method `milestone' for #

I need a "clean" way to be able to find the master parent milestone information.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand "Milestones can have multiple nodes because it's possible to create aliases.".

Comment: second option does not work because you need apply `first` method at the end of chain

Answer (score 1):

You need some scopes and class methods in Node model

```
scope :aliases, where(is_alias: true)
scope :masters, where(is_alias: false)

def self.master
  masters.first
end
```

So you can use this that way

```
@milestone.nodes.master  # => master node
@milestone.nodes.aliases # => aliases
```

Comment: Of course! without the "first" method, rails assumes it is a collection even though I know that there is only one record in the result. Thank's a lot! Any idea why my option 1 (defining an association) doesn't work?

Comment: option 1 not works because at first you need separately assign node `@milestone.node = [some_node]`